# How do i centre a div in angular 5

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular5

I am using Angular5, and I have tried to set `margin: 0 auto` as well as setting `left: 50%` and `top: 50%` but the margin doesn't do anything and setting left to 50% only aligns the side of the div to the middle and doesn't move the div down at all.

How do I align the div #loading to the middle?

My code:

```css
#loading, #outlet {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#loading{
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    padding: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#app{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div id="outlet">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div id="loading" *ngIf="data.Loading">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am also overlaying the #loading div over #outlet.

Comment: Add this #loading{display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;}

Comment: Remove absolute positioning from #loading. Just remove the code: #loading, #outlet {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is because of the `position: absolute` thing that you have assigned to both `#loading` and `#outlet`. You can solve the issue with this code. Try this.

```
<div id="app">
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="outlet">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div id="loading" *ngIf="data.Loading">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

#wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
}
#loading, #outlet {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#loading{
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    padding: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#app{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To align the text in the center, use `text-align: center`:

```css
#loading, #outlet {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#loading{
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    padding: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#app{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div id="outlet">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div id="loading" *ngIf="data.Loading">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

To align the box in the center, use `margin: auto`, but *DO NOT* use `position: absolute`:

```css
#loading, #outlet {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#loading{
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    padding: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#app{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div id="outlet">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div id="loading" *ngIf="data.Loading">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then if you put those two together, you get:

```css
#loading, #outlet {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#loading{
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    padding: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#app{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div id="outlet">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div id="loading" *ngIf="data.Loading">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```